# Delphi Form Flickering

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have an application created by  Delphi XE2 having one form. When the application runs the form flicker to the Desktop it is no smooth. I have set "Double Buffer" and "Parent's Double Buffer" are true to the all possibilities. But the form ficler is present. Then I have added one FadeInTimer and it works fine. I question is "Without any Timer Delphi Form Flickering can be removed or not" . If possible please tell me how ?

Here is my code :

```
unit KoushikHalder01;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.ComCtrls;
type
  TForm01 = class(TForm)
    Label01: TLabel;
    Edit01: TEdit;
    Edit02: TEdit;
    BitBtn01: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn02: TBitBtn;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormHide(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn01MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn02MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn01MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure BitBtn02MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure BitBtn01MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn02MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn02Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form01: TForm01;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses System.IOUtils;

procedure TForm01.BitBtn01Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Attributes: TFileAttributes;
  SL: TStringList;
  Idx: Integer;
begin
   Attributes := [];
   TFile.SetAttributes('C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts', Attributes);
   SL := TStringList.Create;
   try
      SL.LoadFromFile('C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts');

     if
        SL.IndexOf('10.220.70.34    VIRTSDP25') <> -1
     then
        begin
        Edit02.Text := 'Your Host File Has Already Been Modified Successfully.';
        end;
     if
        SL.IndexOf('10.220.70.34    VIRTSDP25') = -1
     then
        begin
        SL.Add('10.220.70.34    VIRTSDP25');
        Edit02.Text := 'Your Host File Has Been Modified Successfully.';
        end;
     if
        SL.IndexOf('10.220.70.32    BSNLESDP25A') = -1
     then
        SL.Add('10.220.70.32    BSNLESDP25A');
     if
        SL.IndexOf('10.220.70.33    BSNLESDP25B') = -1
     then
        SL.Add('10.220.70.33    BSNLESDP25B');
     if
        SL.IndexOf('10.220.70.34    VIRTBSNLESDP25') = -1
     then
        SL.Add('10.220.70.34    VIRTBSNLESDP25');
     if
        SL.IndexOf('10.220.70.34    KOSDPTwentyfive.bsnl.in.net') = -1
     then
        SL.Add('10.220.70.34    KOSDPTwentyfive.bsnl.in.net');
     if
        SL.IndexOf('10.220.70.34    KOSDPTwentyfive.bsnl.net.in') = -1
     then
        begin
           SL.Add('10.220.70.34 KOSDPTwentyfive.bsnl.net.in');
           SL.SaveToFile('C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts');
        end;
     finally
       SL.Free;
   end;
    Include(Attributes, TFileAttribute.faSystem);
    Include(Attributes, TFileAttribute.faReadOnly);
    TFile.SetAttributes('C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts', Attributes);
end;

procedure TForm01.BitBtn01MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
   BitBtn01.Font.Color :=10379745;
end;

procedure TForm01.BitBtn01MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
   BitBtn01.Font.Color :=16711825;
end;

procedure TForm01.BitBtn01MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
   BitBtn01.Font.Color :=15756035;
end;

procedure TForm01.BitBtn02Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form01.Close;
end;

procedure TForm01.BitBtn02MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
   BitBtn02.Font.Color :=10379745;
end;

procedure TForm01.BitBtn02MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
   BitBtn02.Font.Color :=16711825;
end;

procedure TForm01.BitBtn02MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
   BitBtn02.Font.Color :=15756035;
end;

procedure TForm01.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
   Doublebuffered := True;
end;

procedure TForm01.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Doublebuffered := True;
end;

procedure TForm01.FormHide(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Doublebuffered := True;
end;

procedure TForm01.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Doublebuffered := True;
end;

end.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "flicker"? Do other applications' windows on your computer flicker? Post repro code.

Comment: Form flickering means that when the application runs one Blink is there. Other applications on my computer dont have this. I have uploaded my project file in Hotfile. Please download and seee. Please help me.
Here is the download link :
http://hotfile.com/dl/139737012/08f4647/KoushikHalder.7z.html

Comment: Start by removing all of the repeated setting of `DoubleBuffered`. Set it once (if needed) and leave it alone. Changes in `DoubleBuffered` has side effects, as you can see in `TWinControl.SetDoubleBuffered` - it's not a simple property setting when changed. All of the code in `BitBtn01Click` is irrelevant to the question asked here.

Answer (score 2):

DoubleBuffered doesn't always fix flicker, and in some situations can make things worse. You may consider only using DoubleBuffered during resizing, and then switch it back off when resizing is done. This property should only be used on those controls which are actually being resized. For example, when resizing the form, enable DoubleBuffered on the form. But when resizing just the contents of a panel, enable it just for that panel (and all its child controls).

But here are some tips from [A Collection of Delphi Tips & Tricks](http://www.physic.ut.ee/~kiisk/delphi.pdf)
 (PDF)

Avoid flickering in graphics programming
There are four ways to reduce flickering:

1. Use the DoubleBuffered property of TWinControl descendants: set    DoubleBuffered := true;
2. If your control is not transparent, include    csOpaque in ControlStyle: ControlStyle := ControlStyle    + [csOpaque];
3. Handle the WM_ERASEBKGND Windows message and set Msg.Result := 1;
4. in the handler Use off-screen bitmaps (like    double-buffering, but works for any control)